# VBA - Integrate cancel button in Userform to cancel whole macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code (thanks JohnM!) where I use the user input in the Userform to use further in my macro.
I want to incorporate a cancel button in the Userform and when that is clicked, the main macro stops as well. The same if the Userform is being closed by the "X" on the right side above.
Whatever I tried, I cannot manage to stop the main macro running.
The 'unload me' isn't working and I tried to create a variable that checks if the cancel button / close button has been clicked but I wasn't successful.

Main UserForm:

```
Option Explicit

Public Lead_time As Double

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' simpler setting of values into ListBox
    ListBox1.List = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_OK_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            ' get value (not index) of (first) selected item from ListBox
            Lead_time = CDbl(ListBox1.List(i))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If Lead_time = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Select the numbers of lead time"
    Else
        ' hide, but don't destroy, the UserForm to keep the 'Lead_time' variable alive
        Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

Used this part in my code:

```
Dim Lead_time As Long
With New Days_lead_time
    .Show 
    ' because we have not Unloaded the UserForm, we can still access its members
    Lead_time = .Lead_time
End With
MsgBox Lead_time
```

How can I integrate the cancel userform with the code here above?

Comment: At the top of the userform, add "Public OK as boolean". In the Cmd_Ok_Click routine, add OK = True (where appropriate!). Now you can check for the value of OK in your calling code. Make sure to use the QueryClose event of the userform to handle the user clicking the x gracefully.

Comment: [Using UserForm_QueryClose to Cancel the UserForm](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-userform/#Using_UserForm_QueryClose_to_Cancel_the_UserForm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it this way:

```
Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = m_Cancelled
End Property

Private Sub buttonCancel_Click()
    Hide
    m_Cancelled = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer _
                                  , CloseMode As Integer)
    
    ' Prevent the form being unloaded
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True
    
    ' Hide the Userform and set cancelled to true
    Hide
    m_Cancelled = True
    
End Sub
```

Integrated it as follows

```
frm.Show
If frm.Cancelled = True Then
MsgBox "The macro has been cancelled."
Unload frm
Set frm = Nothing
Exit Sub
Else
Lead_time = frm.Lead_time
Unload frm
Set frm = Nothing
End If
```